# Find Names and Lastnames y MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns: Names and Surnames. Users can search in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', nombres, apellidos) LIKE '%Alex Manuel Lewin Rodriguez%';

SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', nombres, apellidos) LIKE '%Alex Lewin%';
```

the last query does not generate any results. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is obvious that '%Alex Lewin%' is not like "Alex Manuel Lewin Rodriguez" for the missing name, you need to do two likes like the answer below

Answer (score 1):

How about you swap like logic, compare column with your string

```
SELECT * 
FROM clientes 
WHERE 'Alex Manuel Lewin Rodriguez' LIKE CONCAT('%', nombres, '%')
  AND 'Alex Manuel Lewin Rodriguez' LIKE CONCAT('%', apellidos, '%')
```